# python logger.error dosn't ' write to error log when file is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have configured the flask logger like this :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logsdir = 'logs/'
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logsdir + "log.log", maxBytes=20480000, backupCount=50)
# Create Error handler
error_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logsdir + "error_logger.log", maxBytes=20480000, backupCount=50)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.addHandler(error_handler)
```

now im executing this open file on NONE exist directory i expect it to fail

```
myfile = utils.open_file("/home/test.txt),"w+")
```

and the function :

```
def open_file(self, file_name, file_mode):
    file_handler = None
    try:
        file_handler = open(file_name, file_mode)
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error("%s exception: %s - %s failed onfile  %s mode %s"
                     ("open_file", current_user.username, repr(err), file_name, file_mode))
    return file_handler
```

i like it to write to the error log file i defined and into the prompt 
the problem is that it's not written to the error log file
i suspect that the exception itself have exception ...
this is the stderr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\app\utiils\utils.py", line 187, in open_file
    file_handler = open(file_name, file_mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/test.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\middleware\proxy_fix.py", line 169, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\git\app\app.py", line 1525, in fresh_install_instances

  File "C:\git\app\utiils\utils.py", line 190, in open_file
    ("open_file", current_user.username, repr(err), file_name, file_mode))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

my question is why its not written to the error log , 
other error log do write to the file .

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the line `logger.error("%s exception: %s - %s failed onfile  %s mode %s"`.

Comment: i have comma :
"%s exception: %s - %s failed onfile  %s mode %s"

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  There is definitely no comma (`,`) at the end of that line, and that fits with the error message `'str' object is not callable`: without the comma you are basically trying to do `"some string"(some_args, ...)`, which will raise that error.